# Recreating minifig scale Junkbot

Tags: part-identification, minifigures, video-games

My goal is to recreate Junkbot from the eponymous LEGO web games with standard parts. Is it possible?

[image: Junkbot]

(He also had cameos on a [recent Ninjago City set](https://www.reddit.com/r/lego/comments/d173wv/junkbot_arcade_game_from_ninjago_city/) *and* [Haunted House set 10273, appearing blank](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=m7GQ_onIM04&t=5m19s), as well as an excellent [LEGO IDEAS fan build](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/30a87ea8-38be-4d83-9d16-656285aba5d6))

The torso looks to be a standard 2x2 orange brick with recycle and face pattern and head looks to be a slope brick with a lines pattern. I looked through Bricklink's decorated slope 45 2x2 but didn't find any matching orange pieces. The "hair" is a regular 1x2 yellow tile. I also wonder if his legs are any standard part. I tried looking through Bricklink's minifig decorated leg section but there were too many to sort through.

Comment: Don't forget Jason's 8:1 scale version of Junkbot! [jkbrickworks.com](https://jkbrickworks.com/junkbot/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All four of these parts are standard and available in those colours. The issue is that the design of the character is not based on any printed bricks so you would have to create your own decals.

[image]

| Part | ID | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brick 2 x 2 | 3003 | Orange |
| Slope 45 2 x 2 | 3039 | Orange |
| Hips and Legs | 970c00 | Light Bluish Gray |
| Tile 1 x 2 | 3069b | Yellow |

Comment: Ah, that's what I figured. I have some slope pieces that do have horizontal lines so I was hoping there was a piece that looked like that.

Comment: by the way how did you make that render? stud.io with custom minifig?

Comment: Yes. I was actually trying to use the decal editing software but it only saved one leg of the minifig legs and I was not so keen using it so I did the decals with Photoshop.

Answer (score 4):

I made a [decal sheet for Junkbot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/1j01/janitorial-android/eb76cdc7f40c7a30f425ef60712dade0c0add8a9/junkbot-decal-sheet.svg), as well as the gearbots.

I made it in a papercraft sort of style, because I don't have an orange slanted brick, so I wanted a decal to cover the whole brick. But you can cut it up to get just the parts you want, with scissors or Inkscape.

There are different layers that can be hidden in Inkscape, such as the annotations.

[image: Junkbot decal sheet at 192 dpi (click for SVG)]

Decalling notes:

- Do the hardest parts first, in case you mess up

  - In particular, do the most intricate cuts first, so that:

    1. you have paper to hold onto while cutting (it's also good to leave a margin around things you're cutting out for that purpose)
    2. it's not as brittle yet (every cut reduces structural integrity)
    3. and in case you mess up
- Use colored markers on white edges

  - Be careful to get a mild enough color of marker (test it first)
  - Be careful not to blotch (don't hold it in one place too much)
  - If you do blotch it like I did, you may be able to save it by markering the whole decal, making it more vibrant in the end
- For the back of Junkbot (after making other folds), form the decal around
  Junkbot's body pieces to start a crease, then pull the paper away and pinch it.
- Precurl curved decals by pushing gently into a surface, or curling around a pen, or just using your fingers. The ends are the most important because they're what will stick up if the paper wants to be flat.
- Use a barrel for the recycle bin so it can be actually hollow, then stuff scraps from the decalling process in for the trash :)
- Attach double sided tape to bricks, then press decals to them. But for precision with *curved* decals, attach the tape to the very end of the decal.

[image: Photo of Junkbot, Gearbot (missing a gear), crate, recycling bin, and Climbbot]

I didn't have enough gears, or a black dome piece, so I made this zany, fearsome bossbot... with a tie or scimitar, your pick:

[image: conic bossbot]

Comment: Very charming. Are the eyebots that tall? I haven't played the game in a few years.

Comment: No, I didn't have the pieces to make the Eyebot, but I wanted to still use the eye decal I made. That said, the bots aren't exactly to scale with the LEGO pieces they're apparently made from (especially the propeller). If you want to play the game, I'm working on an HTML5 remake here: https://github.com/1j01/janitorial-android

Comment: Wow, are there any remakes for Beltz and Dreamz? The only way I got those to work past their removal was from a Russian Bionicles site but it's been a long time since I've played with thos

Comment: @qwr Have you tried [BioMedia Project](http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/)? They focus mainly on Bionicle, but they also have an [archive of old Lego games](http://biomediaproject.com/bmp/files/LEGO/gms/online/)

Comment: @MatthewJensen Yeah that's the Bionicles site I was talking about. A few years ago I had an issue running one of the games and I had to email one of their staff people to get a custom modified file. But since Junkbot is getting a cleanroom implementation, I guess Beltz would be possible too.